# Decoding hex(?) packets

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, rtmp

Using the rtmplib bindings for Python and experiencing some issues.

First off,

I have something like this:

```
import librtmp

conn = librtmp.RTMP(...)
conn.connect()

while True:
  packet = conn.read_packet().body
  print packet
```

This will print the packets like shown below:

[image: example]

To me this looks like hex, and i get 4 char strings when writing to a file, like this:

```
0200 086f 6e42 5744 6f6e 6500 0000 0000
0000 0000 0500 0000 0000 0000 0000 0200
066e 6f74 6963 6500 0000 0000 0000 0000
0502 0003 2a2a 2a02 000a 5072 6f63 6573
```

So my question is, how can i turn this into a real string (or buffer) with only readable text? I've tried different things to decode hex, but end up with "\x05" in the result.

Also worth mentioning that when writing it contains alot of 00's.

Anyone know how can i achieve what i asked earlier in a easy but good way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is `librtmp.amf.decode_amf`.

```
import librtmp

conn = librtmp.RTMP(...)
conn.connect()

while True:
  packet = conn.read_packet().body
  print packet
  print librtmp.amf.decode_amf(packet)
```

This was pointed out by the guy managing the librtmp wrapper for Python.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know what you're going to get then save the data to a file and take a look at it with a viewer?  (e.g. od on linux).

Also if you don't know what data you're going to receive then see if you can't find a description of the format for whatever rtmp gives you online.  (I think since things like red5 exist this should be documented).. and lo there's some documentation http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/rtmp/pdf/rtmp_specification_1.0.pdf

If you know what you're getting you can unpack the data with the struct inbuilt library
https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html

I'm kind of surprised that librtmp doesn't give you the high level parsed objects though.  You can't be the first person to want to do this.. so see if someone else has a lib to handle this.

Comment: I'm looking into struct now after doing some research. Using `print repr(packet)` prints something thats somewhat more readable. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Accepted your answer, also found out there is a function called `librtmp.amf.decode_amf` to decode it. Stupid of me to not think of amf, when i've worked with RTMP before.

Comment: Nice.. thanks for adding the reference to the lib.  You should probably have submitted that as an answer and accepted it.  It's a better answer than mine.